# ERROR: Can't get Master address from zookeeper; znode data == null value

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I have two linux machine one is `master machine(192.168.8.174)` and another one is `slave machine(192.168.8.173)`. I have installed and configured Hadoop 2.6.0 in fully distributed mode successfully. Hadoop output also coming perfectly. I installed and configured HBase 1.0. When I start hbase the output like below

```
master machine                  slave machine
HMaster                         HQuorumpeer                         
HQuorumpeer                     RegionServer
HRegionServer
```

But when I `create table(EXAMPLE:create 'test','cf')` it shows error like below in hbase log file

```
015-03-19 16:46:04,930 INFO  [master/master/192.168.8.174:16020-SendThread(192.168.8.173:2181)] zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Opening socket connection to server 192.168.8.173/192.168.8.173:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
2015-03-19 16:46:04,952 INFO  [master/master/192.168.8.174:16020-SendThread(192.168.8.173:2181)] zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Socket connection established to 192.168.8.173/192.168.8.173:2181, initiating session
2015-03-19 16:46:04,963 INFO  [master/master/192.168.8.174:16020-SendThread(192.168.8.173:2181)] zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Session establishment complete on server 192.168.8.173/192.168.8.173:2181, sessionid = 0x14c3135d05c0001, negotiated timeout = 90000
2015-03-19 16:46:04,964 INFO  [master/master/192.168.8.174:16020] client.ZooKeeperRegistry: ClusterId read in ZooKeeper is null
2015-03-19 16:46:04,992 FATAL [master:16020.activeMasterManager] master.HMaster: Failed to become active master
java.net.ConnectException: Call From master/192.168.8.174 to master:54310 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapWithMessage(NetUtils.java:783)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapException(NetUtils.java:730)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1364)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:206)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy15.setSafeMode(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:187)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:102)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy15.setSafeMode(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.setSafeMode(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:602)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.fs.HFileSystem$1.invoke(HFileSystem.java:279)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy16.setSafeMode(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.setSafeMode(DFSClient.java:2264)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.setSafeMode(DistributedFileSystem.java:986)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.setSafeMode(DistributedFileSystem.java:970)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.FSUtils.isInSafeMode(FSUtils.java:447)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.FSUtils.waitOnSafeMode(FSUtils.java:894)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.MasterFileSystem.checkRootDir(MasterFileSystem.java:416)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.MasterFileSystem.createInitialFileSystemLayout(MasterFileSystem.java:145)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.MasterFileSystem.<init>(MasterFileSystem.java:125)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.finishActiveMasterInitialization(HMaster.java:591)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.access$500(HMaster.java:165)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster$1.run(HMaster.java:1425)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:739)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketIOWithTimeout.connect(SocketIOWithTimeout.java:206)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:529)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:493)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupConnection(Client.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupIOstreams(Client.java:700)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.access$2800(Client.java:367)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.getConnection(Client.java:1463)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1382)
    ... 29 more
2015-03-19 16:46:05,002 FATAL [master:16020.activeMasterManager] master.HMaster: Unhandled exception. Starting shutdown.
java.net.ConnectException: Call From master/192.168.8.174 to master:54310 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapWithMessage(NetUtils.java:783)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapException(NetUtils.java:730)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1364)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:206)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy15.setSafeMode(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:187)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:102)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy15.setSafeMode(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.setSafeMode(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:602)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.fs.HFileSystem$1.invoke(HFileSystem.java:279)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy16.setSafeMode(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.setSafeMode(DFSClient.java:2264)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.setSafeMode(DistributedFileSystem.java:986)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.setSafeMode(DistributedFileSystem.java:970)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.FSUtils.isInSafeMode(FSUtils.java:447)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.FSUtils.waitOnSafeMode(FSUtils.java:894)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.MasterFileSystem.checkRootDir(MasterFileSystem.java:416)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.MasterFileSystem.createInitialFileSystemLayout(MasterFileSystem.java:145)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.MasterFileSystem.<init>(MasterFileSystem.java:125)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.finishActiveMasterInitialization(HMaster.java:591)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.access$500(HMaster.java:165)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster$1.run(HMaster.java:1425)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:739)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketIOWithTimeout.connect(SocketIOWithTimeout.java:206)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:529)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:493)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupConnection(Client.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupIOstreams(Client.java:700)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.access$2800(Client.java:367)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.getConnection(Client.java:1463)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1382)
    ... 29 more
2015-03-19 16:46:05,002 INFO  [master:16020.activeMasterManager] regionserver.HRegionServer: STOPPED: Unhandled exception. Starting shutdown.
2015-03-19 16:46:08,046 INFO  [master/master/192.168.8.174:16020] ipc.RpcServer: Stopping server on 16020
2015-03-19 16:46:08,046 INFO  [RpcServer.listener,port=16020] ipc.RpcServer: RpcServer.listener,port=16020: stopping
2015-03-19 16:46:08,047 INFO  [RpcServer.responder] ipc.RpcServer: RpcServer.responder: stopped
2015-03-19 16:46:08,047 INFO  [RpcServer.responder] ipc.RpcServer: RpcServer.responder: stopping
2015-03-19 16:46:08,049 INFO  [master/master/192.168.8.174:16020] regionserver.HRegionServer: Stopping infoServer
2015-03-19 16:46:08,089 INFO  [master/master/192.168.8.174:16020] mortbay.log: Stopped SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:16030
2015-03-19 16:46:08,191 INFO  [master/master/192.168.8.174:16020] regionserver.HRegionServer: stopping server master,16020,1426754759593
2015-03-19 16:46:08,191 INFO  [master/master/192.168.8.174:16020] client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: Closing zookeeper sessionid=0x14c3135d05c0001
2015-03-19 16:46:08,241 INFO  [master/master/192.168.8.174:16020-EventThread] zookeeper.ClientCnxn: EventThread shut down
2015-03-19 16:46:08,242 INFO  [master/master/192.168.8.174:16020] zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Session: 0x14c3135d05c0001 closed
2015-03-19 16:46:08,244 INFO  [master/master/192.168.8.174:16020] regionserver.HRegionServer: stopping server master,16020,1426754759593; all regions closed.
```

So I can't understand what is the problem

my configuration files are

master machine - `hbase-site.xml`

```
    <configuration>
    <property>
         <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
            <value>hdfs://192.168.8.174:54310/hbase</value>
     </property> 
     <property>
            <name>hbase.cluster.distributed</name>
            <value>true</value>
     </property>
    <property>
        <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.dataDir</name>
        <value>hdfs://192.168.8.174:9002/zookeeper</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum</name>
        <value>192.168.8.174,192.168.8.173</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort</name>
        <value>2181</value>
    </property>
    </configuration>
```

slave machine - `hbase-site.xml`

```
 <configuration>
        <property>
             <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
             <value>hdfs://192.168.8.174:54310/hbase</value>
         </property> 
         <property>
                <name>hbase.cluster.distributed</name>
                <value>true</value>
         </property>

        </configuration>
```

and I enabled `HBASE_MANAGES_ZK` is true in `hbase-env.sh`

Answer (score 4):

I got `ERROR: Can't get master address from ZooKeeper; znode data == null` once before. In my case it was the configuration of the `zookeeper.znode.parent` value. The value on the server was `/hbase` but I could only connect if it is set to `/hbase-unsecure` from the client. Had to edit that value on the server's zoo.cfg file for the client to connect to it.

Answer (score 0):

From the log message, it looks like you may have an issue with name resolution.

I would make sure that your IP addresses properly resolve in both the forward and reverse direction to the same hostname. This is a common problem with HBase. In particular, I would check your `/etc/hosts` file and make sure that the name `master` is not associated with the IP address `192.168.8.174`. If it is, then you'll need to use the proper name in your configuration instead of IP addresses. Also, make sure the name mappings are the same on all machines in your cluster. There are tools for doing this check for you, for example:

https://github.com/sujee/hadoop-dns-checker

UPDATE: It looks like you may also have a bad setting for `hbase.zookeeper.property.dataDir`. You currently have it pointed to an HDFS url, but I believe this is supposed to be a local directory path. See [here](http://hbase.apache.org/book.html#_get_started_with_hbase) for an example.

I would confirm that you can even talk to zookeeper from the command line using `hbase zkcli`.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. My master machine and slave machines `/etc/hosts` configuration as  
`192.168.8.174  master 
192.168.8.173  slave1`.

Please help me how to resolve the problem.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you also have entries that map `master` to either `127.0.0.1` or `127.0.1.1`? Those can confuse HBase. For a large cluster `/etc/hosts` is not a good solution. I would recommend setting up proper DNS entries.

Comment: sorry i don't understand what do you mean in above command but in my both machines hosts file doesn't have `localhost or 127.0.0.1`. only i mention `192.168.8.174 master 192.168.8.173 slave1`. give some detail solution

Comment: Thanks for the reply.The zookeeper data directory also i changed to local directory . i checked with the hbase zkcli command and it shows the zk is connected status.`([zk : 192.168.8.173:2181,192.168.8.174:2181(CONNECTED) 0)])` . I checked with the hbase shell command the same error is coming now `ERROR : Can't get master address from Zookeeper; znode data= null`.I dont know where is the problem.Please help me.